# Как можно с помощью CSS выбрать первый li, только тогда, когда их всего 3, а если 2 или 1, то не выбирать?

Tags: css, css3, html5, вёрстка, css-selectors

Как можно с помощью CSS выбрать первый `li`, только тогда, когда их всего 3, а если 2 или 1, то не выбирать?

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: С помощью JS можно это легко реализовать, добавив проверку на количество дочерних элементов. Если оно равно 3, то добавить к первому элементу li определенный класс и стилизовать его в CSS.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр, мне просто через CSS, по возможности, нужно было это сделать

Answer (score 4):

Решено:

```css
li:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(3) {
  background-color: #9d89ff;
}
```

Comment: Получается селектор срабатывает только тогда, когда `:nth-last-child` попадает на `:nth-child`, т.е. применить его при динамическом количестве элементов не получится((